# value +1 after page refresh and database check

Tags: php, html, database, loops, mysqli

I have 4 checkboxes for example (Can be more can be less).
[image: The 4 checkboxes]
And i have a database table that looks like this:

```
+----------+----------+
|    id    | value    |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |     NULL |
|        2 |     NULL |
|        3 |     NULL |
|        4 |     NULL |
+----------+----------+
```

Now when i select 2 boxes, and press: Save. (The save button inserts the values in the db and refreshes the page)

The database inserts the value 1.
This is how the screen and database look like after i selected and saved 2 selections:

[image: After i inserted 2 checkboxes]

```
+----------+----------+
|    id    | value    |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |
|        3 |     NULL |
|        4 |     NULL |
+----------+----------+
```

Now this is good, however i would like the next values to be 2.
But i don't know how!

Code:

```
<?php    
    $x = 1;  
    foreach($show_axle as $bogiebox){ ?>

    <td>
        <?php 
            if($bogiebox['bogie_nr'] == ''){
        ?>
            <input type='hidden' 
                   name='bogie_id[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' 
                   value='<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>'>

            <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" 
                   value="<?= $x ?>" 
                   name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]'>
            </td>
        <?php
            }
            else{ 
        ?>
            <input type='checkbox' 
                   id="bogie_axle_fields" 
                   checked disabled></td><?php } 
    }
?>
```

**bogie_nr** and **bogie_id** are the values i used in the example!

the function just gets the value where ID = ID so no need to put that here.

**EDIT:**

I don't want the value to be 1-2-3-4-5 etc. etc. for every checkbox. i want them to all have 1 value. and after insert they al should have ++ value.

Like this:

[image: What i want it to look like]

Comment: incrementing x in each iteration will do it for you

Comment: yeah increment x here :`... id="bogie_axle_fields" value="<?= $x ?>"...` change it to `...id="bogie_axle_fields" value="<?= $x++ ?>"....` or use another query to find the highest number `SELECT top 1 value+1 FROM bogie_Table `

Comment: `Now this is good, however i would like the next values to be 2.` - getting `1` for both of the first checkboxes is being described as a good scenario so regular +1 increment isn't the solution. **I would ask the OP what's the logic behind it...**

Comment: @OfirBaruch ah nice spot. ambiguos a little. so each refresh you want the value to increment. example select **3** first time they **all 1**, select the **4th** one next time and it is **2**? as in my comment above you will have to use a seperate query to the DB. i forgot to order it so like : `SELECT top 1 (value+1) as value FROM bogie_Table ORDER BY value DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I have got the answer!
I made a new function:

```
function bogie_value($id){
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(bogie_nr) AS bogie_nr FROM bogie WHERE train_id = :id2";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":id2", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Then I made a loop:

```
$bogie_value = $database->bogie_value($_GET['train_id']);

foreach($bogie_value as $get_max_value){
    $get_max_value['bogie_nr'];
}
```

Then:

```
$x = $get_max_value['bogie_nr'] +1;
$x;
```

Thanks for all the quick responses!! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also update your record by using the existing number and add 1

```
UPDATE table SET value = value + 1 WHERE id =1
```

Comment: +1 because it answered the question as I understood it... but I'm not sure I understood it right... and also it might be needed to set default values of database fields to 0.

Comment: Il give this a try! :)

Comment: @Bartdude if column type is `INT` there is no need to set it default.

Answer (score 2):

Update to this:

```
    <?php    
    $x = 1;  
    foreach($show_axle as $bogiebox){ 
    ?>
        <td>
            <?php 
            if($bogiebox['bogie_nr'] == ''){
            ?>
                <input type='hidden' name='bogie_id[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>'>
                <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" value="<?= $x ?>" name='bogie_nr[<?php echo $bogiebox['bogie_id']?>]'></td>
            <?php
            } else { 
            ?>
                <input type='checkbox' id="bogie_axle_fields" checked disabled>
        </td>
        <?php }
        $x++;
    }
?>
```

What it does: after every `foreach` it will add +1 to the `$x` variable, so it will go: [ 1 , 2 , 3 , .. ]

**EDIT**

Use this SQL at the beginning of your code, and set the (`$x` + 1) variable as the result of the SQL.

SQL `SELECT MAX(value) FROM table_checkbox`

The `SQL` select the maximum value from the table, then you add +1 to the result value and set it to the variable `$x`.

Comment: Please notice that you put the increment command in the `else` statement so it won't increase as you've described.

Comment: @OfirBaruch if you have a closer look, at the end of the `input` line, it has the `}` which closes the `else` statement.

Comment: @OfirBaruch updated the code so other don't get confused with code identation.

Comment: You're right.
And that's why I hate combining HTML and PHP ;)

Comment: It's working like that i know. But i actually want them all to be the same value. and nog be like 1 - x. (Look at my last database code) It goes 1-1-2-2 and not 1-2-3-4

Comment: @Mitch  check my edit, I think it is going to work this way now.

Comment: @Mitch oh, alright, could you post the answer, so it helps others.

Comment: i did 32 minuts ago hahah

Answer (score 1):

So each refresh you want the value to increment. example select 3 first time they all 1, select the 4th one next time and it is 2? as in my comment above you will have to use a seperate query to the DB. like :

```
SELECT top 1 (value+1) as value 
FROM bogie_Table ORDER BY value DESC
```

output will be like

```
+--------+
| value  |
+--------+
|      2 |
+--------+
```

If it is a session scenario you can store the number of submits in a session variable *(sessionStorage/localStorage/cookie)*

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["numberOfSubmits"]);
    session_start();

$x = $_SESSION['numberOfSubmits'] + 1;
//...
```

and when you are done or want to start over use

```
session_unset()//removes all session variables;
```

[source w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: If i use the session, how does he know when to do ++ ?? do i have to put the submit button in a session??

Comment: you would have to set the session variable, each time the user clicks save. `save logic then $_SESSION['numberOfSubmits'] = $x;` keep in mind if the save fails for some reason the session variable will still be incremented